# Linux Dual Boot Macbook Pro 15

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, osx, dual-boot, macintosh

I am looking to dual boot my MBP 15". I have read mixed opinions on this one webpage specifically says it won't work due to the Force touch trackpad. But on some reddit forums i have seen people say they use it on their MBP 2015.

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
Model Name: MacBook Pro
Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,4
Processor Name: Intel Core i7
Processor Speed: 2.8 GHz
Number of Processors: 1
Total Number of Cores: 4
L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
L3 Cache: 6 MB
Memory: 16 GB
SMC Version (system): 2.29f24
```

I am currently running

```
MacOs Sierra 10.12.6

Is it possible to Dual Boot Mac Os and Linux on the MacBook above?
How to do it?
Is there any limitations?
```